# Where does Windows PowerShell set $profile?

Tags: powershell

I would like to move my default "My Documents\WindowsPowerShell" folder. However, when I try this, PowerShell of course can't find $profile. Is there a file or something that I can edit to point PowerShell to a different startup folder?

Comment: Why not just dot source your file in the regular profile?

Comment: Because I'd like to move the whole WindowsPowerShell folder. However, if that turns out to be impossible, your suggestion will be the perfect compromise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I can suggest is that you dot source the file having the content of your profile in the file `$profile.AllUsersAllHosts`

`$profile.AllUsersAllHosts` is something like `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`

Related question: [Is it possible to change the default value of $profile to a new value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095509/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-value-of-profile-to-a-new-value)

Comment: Hmm, I do not have a file of that name. Should there be one? There is a folder called 'examples' there which has a profile.ps1 in it though.

Comment: @charles Anderson You will have to create. None of the profile files are created initially as far as I know. Just do `New-Item -path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts -type file -force`
`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) from Sysinternals to make the `WindowsPowershell` directory a symbolic link to another location (but not a network drive).

You could do this if you wanted to store the profile scripts at `C:\POSH`

```
junction.exe "$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell" 'C:\POSH'
```

Comment: I am using this with no issues. I used the Powershell Community Extensions PSCX cmdlet new-symlink to do the same thing.

Comment: note, Junctions and [Windows 10 Symbolic Links](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#w22Irqj0V76jeb9w.97) are different.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't do that. The user profile location is always under 'My Documents\WindowsPowerShell' and your only option is to relocate your documents folder (folder redirection).

Answer (score 0):

By default `$Profile/$Home/$PSModulePath` are all within the registry... normally under

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment` for User environment variables
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` for System environment variables
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

and elsewhere!