# How can I change the profile related path variables?

Tags: powershell

The organization has changed my "home" server location and has it configured so that I cannot have files in %USERPROFILE%\Documents. However, when I start PowerShell, it still points to the previous server for some significant variables. How do I change this?

```
PROFILE        \\OLDSERVER\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_prof...
PSCommandPath  \\OLDSERVER\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
PSScriptRoot   \\OLDSERVER\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell
```

This is on PSVersion 5.0.10586.117 on Windows 7.

```
PS H:\My Documents> $profile | get-member -type noteproperty

Name                   MemberType   Definition
----                   ----------   ----------
AllUsersAllHosts       NoteProperty string AllUsersAllHosts=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    NoteProperty string AllUsersCurrentHost=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microso...
CurrentUserAllHosts    NoteProperty string CurrentUserAllHosts=\\OLDSERVER\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowe...
CurrentUserCurrentHost NoteProperty string CurrentUserCurrentHost=\\OLDSERVER\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsP...

PS H:\My Documents> "$Env:USERPROFILE, $Env:HOMEPATH"
C:\Users\lit, \Users\lit
```

Comment: [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx): `$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot` are defined in currently running script. What says `$profile | get-member -type noteproperty`?

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is, that Powershell generates that value out of %USERPROFILE%. [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx)

There are some SO-Questions [no-solutions-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621872/where-does-windows-powershell-set-profile)

But maybe you can work around.
There is an

```
PS > $PROFILE.AllUsersCurrentHost
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

Maybe you can modify your variables by using `$env:USERNAME` or loading the profiles on your server.

Example:
write 
`$PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost += ";\\NEWSERVER\{0}\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_prof.." -f $env:username`
into the ISE Profile in AllUsersCurrentHost

Greetz Eldo.Ob

Comment: Nothing in the cmd.exe environment, including %USERPROFILE%, refers to `OLDSERVER`. From where does PowerShell get this? Also, I would like to find a solution that would work for others and coworkers who have a different "home" server.

Comment: What is `$env:USERPROFILE` telling you? Or `$env:HOMEPATH`

Comment: OR maybe you find your answer here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx - if you set enviromentvariables