# Where to put PowerShell profile scripts if standard locations are forbidden?

Tags: powershell

In our corporate environment, I am having difficulty with creating a PowerShell profile scripts.

To prevent users from writing documents on the local disk, the "Documents" directory is forced to be on a network drive. Commonly the "H:" (home) drive.

Likewise, users are forbidden from writing under C:\Windows\System32.

Where can I put the ISE profile script if these two are not available?

PSVersion 5.0.10586.117

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $HOME, $PSHOME
C:\Users\pwatson
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

See also: Help-About about_Profiles

When I am not connected to the network, these are the $profile settings. I still cannot write under C:\Windows\System32 and the `CurrentUser` values are invalid.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $profile | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString
()}
string AllUsersAllHosts=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
string AllUsersCurrentHost=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
string CurrentUserAllHosts=WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
string CurrentUserCurrentHost=WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

Comment: For my information, you are a user in this enviroment or a admin? Why would the user require writing access to the script?

Comment: @wOxxOm - That is not where Microsoft doc says the scripts can be placed. Do you know that this works?

Comment: @Kage - I am the user. This is my development machine. I have "administrator" permission, but not to write under System32.

Comment: @Liturgist, no, it didn't work, I've removed the comment.

Comment: I have found that I can place a profile.ps1 file at `$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` and the shell will use it. The value is in UNC form, `\\SERVER\SHARE\user\My Documents...`. When I am not connected to the network, I will not have the profile available.

Comment: Can you alter what app handles .ps1 files? So that you'll be able to use your own launcher (.bat or .ps1) that loads custom scripts before launching the file from command line.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Is changing the .ps1 handler something that is permitted? If so, then I probably can.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095509/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-value-of-profile-to-a-new-value

Comment: If you can launch PowerShell from a command prompt (or via a batch file), there's a relatively easy way to change the $HOME profile location. Is this a possibility for you?

Comment: @KenWhite - Yes, I could do such, but I need to consider what other developers and users will need to do. Does this involve changing the HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH before running powershell.exe? It seems that this area has not been well thought through by the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes. It works; tested on three machines. I don't see how it can affect other developers and users; if you're not on the network, you don't have access to a central location, so a common location on each machine (e.g. C:\Scripts) and a batch file that alters %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH% and then launches the PS script will work. The other alternative would be to modify the system env. variables, but (in my case, anyway), our group policy sets up a centralized drive mapping to a users folder on the server which sets %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a shortcut with a target like this:

```
%systemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -file C:\somewhere\myprofile.ps1
```

and then always use this shortcut to start PowerShell.

This is not actually using the built-in PowerShell profile concept but it is dot-sourcing a ps1 file that behaves pretty much like a profile file.

If you like to start PowerShell from cmd.exe, create a batch-file with the same content as above and put it somewhere in your path (if you have permissions to do so)

Comment: I am going to choose this as the answer because someone may be helped by it. I may try this, but I think there may be things lost in not using the designed profile concept. There are still `$PSCommandPath`, `$PSScriptRooot`, and `$env:PSModulePath` to deal with.