# How to change PowerShell default module installation folder?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to change PowerShell module installation folder (the folder that modules are placed after Install-Module)?
This is why I want to do this:

- I'm on Windows 10, PowerShell 5.1.17763.503
- My default installation folder is `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
- My Documents folder have been moved to a location containing `,` symbol (corporate policies)
- PS has a bug loading .ps1 that contain classes and have `,` in the file path (similar to [this issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/16501567-breaking-change-in-classes-behaviour-in-wmf-5-1).)

What I've tried:

- I thought the installation folder is the first folder in the $env:PSModulePath and I can change it. When I've opened "Edit System Environment Variables" I saw the installation folder is not in the `$env:PSModulePath`. It's automatically added on the variable when you start PowerShell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to change the behaviour of `Install-Module` so it installs modules in a custom path.

However, You can use `Install-Module [...] -Scope AllUsers` to install the modules for all users. This would install the modules in `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules`, but this operation requires **elevated permissions** (a.k.a. Local Administrator rights).

If you download and install modules to a custom path yourself (or use an alternative implementation to `Install-Module`), you can modify `$env:PSModulePath` as you wish.

You can use a profile to patch the `$env:PSModulePath` every time you start a PowerShell session by adding this to one of your profiles:

```
# Prepend custom module path.
$env:PSModulePath = ((@("C:\mymodulepath") + ($env:PSModulePath -split ";")) -join ";")
```

From [Modifying the PSModulePath Installation Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path)

> To add paths to this variable, use one of the following methods:
>
> - To add a temporary value that is available only for the current session, run the following command at the command line:
>
>   ```
>   $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";c:\ModulePath"
>   ```
> - To add a persistent value that is available whenever a session is opened, add the following command to a Windows PowerShell profile:
>
>   ```
>   $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";c:\ModulePath"
>   ```
>
> For more information about profiles, see [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles) in the
>   Microsoft TechNet library.
>
> - To add a persistent variable to the registry, create a new user environment variable called `PSModulePath` using the Environment
>     Variables Editor in the System Properties dialog box.
> - To add a persistent variable by using a script, use the `SetEnvironmentVariable` method on the Environment class. For example,
>     the following script adds the `"C:\Program Files\Fabrikam\Module"` path
>     to the value of the `PSModulePath` environment variable for the
>     computer. To add the path to the user `PSModulePath` environment
>     variable, set the target to `"User"`.
>
>   ```
>   $CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
>   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + ";C:\Program Files\Fabrikam\Modules", "Machine")
>   ```

Comment: Unfortunately Install-Module doesn't respect the $env:PSModulePath variable.

Comment: @f0rt There is no way to change the behaviour of `Install-Module` so it installs modules in a custom path, apart from using `AllUsers` scope which will install in ProgramFiles instead. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: [Save-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/save-module) seems to be a solution. You could specify your new module install folder.