# PowerShell $PROFILE, Variables and NoteProperty / Add-Member

Tags: powershell, console, profile

`$profile` is causing me some headaches. `$Profile.GetType()` resolves to `String` which is fine, but it has NoteProperty values:

```
$profile | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty
```

`AllUsersAllHosts, AllUsersCurrentHost, CurrentUserAllHosts, CurrentUserCurrentHost`

When I type `$profile`, the CurrentUserCurrentHost NoteProperty is returned. This is fine, but I need to change this value - it's complicated, but my corporate VPN uses a network profile and when I am online it tries to reference that location for my `$profile` meaning that every console startup takes 9 seconds (horribly slow). I can get that down to 1 sec if the profile is loaded locally, but that means changing these values. To do this, I put the following into the `AllUsersAllHosts` `profile.ps1`

```
$profile = C:\Users\($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
```

That's fine, but by doing this, I find that all of the NoteProperty values are deleted! So I tried:

```
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost = C:\Users\($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
```

But this fails, as the root value of $Profile continues to point at the network profile and Console startup is 9 seconds again!

I then also noticed the following weirdness:

```
$x = [string]$profile
$x -eq $profile
```

Ny main questions are:

• Why does $x return `True` even though $x has none of the `NoteProperty` values in `$profile` (as the objects are definitely not the same!)?

• How do I control what the root value of `$profile` is without destroying the `NoteProperty` values, and

• How can I update `.CurrentUserAllHosts` and `.CurrentUserCurrentHost` in such a way that the root value will also update accordingly? i.e. Even if I do the below, the root value of `$profile` remains unchanged (still points at the very slow network profile location):

```
Add-Member -InputObject $PROFILE -NotePropertyName "AllUsersAllHosts" -NotePropertyValue "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1"
Add-Member -InputObject $PROFILE -NotePropertyName "AllUsersCurrentHost" -NotePropertyValue "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
Add-Member -InputObject $PROFILE -NotePropertyName "CurrentUserAllHosts" -NotePropertyValue "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1"
Add-Member -InputObject $PROFILE -NotePropertyName "CurrentUserCurrentHost" -NotePropertyValue "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is technically possible to copy NoteProperty members from one string instance to another (see below), that won't help you, unfortunately:

PowerShell exposes the `$PROFILE` variable for the *user's* benefit:

- It doesn't use that variable's values *internally* to determine the profile locations when it loads profiles,
- these **profile locations are *not* configurable**.

**You should treat `$PROFILE` as a read-only variable**, even though it can technically be modified.

For **workarounds**, see the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5095509/45375).

If starting interactive sessions is the focus, the most promising approach is to create a dedicated shortcut file (`*.lnk`) for launching your PowerShell sessions, defined with a target command such as the following:

```
powershell -noprofile -noexit -c ". c:\CustomProfileDir\profile.ps1"
```

<sup>To use PowerShell [Core] 6+, substitute `pwsh` for `powershell`.</sup>

---

#### Copying NoteProperty members between objects:

Note:

- As stated, this will *not* solve your problem, but it illustrates how NoteProperty members can be copied from one object to another, even between strings that have different values.
- With `[string]` instances specifically, using `-PassThru` and assigning back to the input variable (`$obj = $obj | Add-Member -PassThru ...`) is required in order for the NoteProperty members to be retained; for other types, `$obj | Add-Member ...` is sufficient.

```
# Assign the new string value to a new (temporary) variable.
$newProfile = '/path/to/my.ps1'

# Copy the NoteProperty members from the original, decorated string
# to the new variable's string instance.
$PROFILE.psobject.properties | where MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' | foreach { 
  $newProfile = $newProfile |
    Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyName $_.Name -NotePropertyValue $_.Value  
}

# You can now assign the new variable to the old one,
# but note that *with $PROFILE that won't help*.
# $PROFILE SHOULD BE TREATED AS READ-ONLY.
$PROFILE = $newProfile
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Very interesting. I guess that all that I can do then is to just blow away `$profile` as I did. Just reassign `$profile = C:\new\path.ps1` but then I have a problem. AllUsersAllHosts will load for *all* hosts (like ISE or VSCode). Do you have any idea how I can get the correct name by querying PowerShell? `host` is no good as it doesn't return `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` for console or `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1` for VSCode. I wonder how PowerShell gets `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1`. If I can do that, then I could extract what I need. Any ideas would be great!?

Comment: @YorSubs, the point was that while you can _technically_ define `$PROFILE` the way you want (as shown in the bottom section of the answer), PowerShell will simply _ignore_ the redefinition. The `Microsoft.VSCode` part comes from the automatic `$ShellId` variable. The bottom line is: you _cannot_ change where PowerShell looks for profile files, but you can use the techniques in the linked answer to work around that.

Comment: You are right. I thought it was operating in the way that I wanted, but that was just a coincidence due to the paths I was using. Horrible that MS do not allow a way to permanently alter the profile locations. Security concerns can't be a reason (as Windows is just a security concern full stop!). Ok, I think what I have to do is make locations delete all profile files in all network path locations and just dotsource from `AllUsersAllHosts`. Really inefficient as I need Admin and can't control everything with user context only, but looks like MS have hardcoded this restriction for us!

Comment: @YorSubs, but won't the slowdown still happen due to PowerShell even _looking_ for the files in the network locations? Also, please don't forget to accept the answer - unless you think there's something missing.

Comment: Apparently not. I don't understand why this slowdown is so dramatic as the VPN works fine and I don't find file transfers so awful - it's taken me about 4 months to realise that this is the source of the slow PS startup times. When I turn off the VPN, the network folder is cached locally (via an H:\ drive) and PS startup is 1 to 1.5 sec (acceptable). Turn on the VPN and bam, starting a PS console is 6.5 to 9 seconds every time but if I use `AllHostsAllUsers` and point to a profile on C:\, then it is quick again! If you have any other ideas, I'm keen to try anything out. :)

Comment: @YorSubs, if this is (mostly) about starting interactive shells, consider defining a dedicated startup shortcut - please see my update.

Comment: I did see that one, thanks Michael, and I'm considering it. Thing is, I want things to work from in a default way, so for example, it's not just about interactive shells because every time I run a script it will load the profile (unless I use -NoProfile), so I still want to bypass that 6.5 to 9 sec delay caused by the tortuous way that it accesses the network share. I'll post what I did as an Answer so that it's formatted properly.

Comment: Understood, @YorSubs. Note that it's quite unfortunate that PowerShell loads profiles _by default_ in non-interactive invocations (which POSIX-like shells sensibly do not do); there are efforts underway to provide a separate executable / symlink that fixes this problem - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8072).

Answer (score 0):

As @mklement0 pointed out, I cannot bypass the functionality of $profile, but I can trick it. Without the below, all shells and scripts take 6.5 to 9 sec to start when I am remotely connected to my corporate VPN (part of that, about 3 seconds is my `$profile` functions etc). With the below, all consoles and scripts startup in 1 second (and that includes my `$profile` functions about 1000 lines of code). Putting this solution here in case of help to others.

Running the code at the bottom of this answer results in pushing the following into my `$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts` which will now always reference a profile at the default C:\ location (and correctly per host type as well - console, ISE, VSCode etc).

```
Set-Location C:\Users\$($env:Username)

# Prevent loading profile from network share
if ($Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost -ne "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$(($Profile).split(`"\`")[-1])") {
    $Profile = "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$(($Profile).split(`"\`")[-1])"
    if (Test-Path "$Profile") { . $Profile }
}
```

All I then need to do is delete any profiles on the network share and now I get 1 second load times whether connected remotely to the VPN or not, and whether I open a console or a script etc.

```
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Do you want to update `$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts to always redirect to C:\Users\$($env:Username) ?"
Write-Host "This can significantly speed up PowerShell load times when working with a network share over a VPN."
Write-Host "Note that this is just a bypass to always use the *default* profile location on C:\."
Write-Host "   `$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1"
Write-Host "   `$Profile.CurrentHostCurrentUser = C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$(($Profile).split("\"))[-1]_profile.ps1"
Write-Host ""

$ProfileAdmin = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1"
# Use  (($Profile).split("\"))[-1]  to capture correct prefix PowerShell, VSCode. $ShellId does not work for VSCode etc
$ProfileUser = "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$(($Profile).split('\')[-1])"
$ProfileUserText = '"C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$(($Profile).split(`"\`")[-1])"'

Write-Host "Press any key to use `$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts to stop using a profile from a network share"
pause
# - Create $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts
# - Set-Location C:\Users\$($env:Username)   (override Admin defaulting into system32)
# - If the system decides that it will use C:\ have to check that so that we do not double-load $Profile!
# - If that condition is ok, set $Profile = "C:\Users\$($env:Username)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\$($ShellId)_profile.ps1"
# - Then just dotsource $Profile as it's set to the C:\ drive as required.
if (!(Test-Path $(Split-Path $ProfileAdmin))) { mkdir $(Split-Path $ProfileAdmin) -Force }
if (!(Test-Path $(Split-Path $ProfileUser))) { mkdir $(Split-Path $ProfileUser) -Force }
Write-Host "`nCreating backup of existing profile ..."
If (Test-Path $ProfileAdmin) { Copy-Item -Path "$($ProfileAdmin)" -Destination "$($ProfileAdmin)_$(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss").txt" }
Set-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "Set-Location C:\Users\`$(`$env:Username)"
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value ""
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "# Prevent loading profile from network share"
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "if (`$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost -ne $ProfileUserText) {"
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "    `$Profile = $ProfileUserText"
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "    if (Test-Path `"`$Profile`") { . `$Profile }"
Add-Content -Path $ProfileAdmin -Value "}"
```