# Powershell $PROFILE variable pointing to wrong location. Where is $PROFILE variable it set?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

After doing some changes to my machine, Powershell fails because the $PROFILE variable points to a different location than before, i.e. it is set to

```
C:\Powershell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Powershell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

This causes problems like installed modules not found and more. So my question is how does Powershell set the value of $PROFILE? Can it be changed?

Comment: The short answer is: You can't.
Long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095509/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-value-of-profile-to-a-new-value

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @SergeanBiggs. I had seen the long answer, but it doesn't explain why the location in my case changed, i.e. how does PowerShell set the $PROFILE variable? But I resolved the issue. See below.

Comment: @arivdar You can change where powershell finds the default profile in the registry. `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`. The key you want to change is `Personal`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this while searching for an answer.

To change where Powershell will look for the default profile you need to change a registry key.

Please note that the profile wil be found under a new directory `WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

Desired path: `C:/Users/admin`
Powershell profile: `C:/Users/admin/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

---

Manual way:

Open up the Registry Editor and navigate to:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Change the value of `Personal` to the directory of your choice.

---

Automated way with powershell:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" -Name "Personal" -Value "DRIVEHERE"`

Then you can test the value was set with:

`Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" -Name "Personal"`

Answer (score 5):

Solved. It turns out that before the problem occurred, $PROFILE had pointed to Documents folder in OneDrive, i.e.

```
C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

When I enabled Documents backup to OneDrive and relogged in the $PROFILE was back to the correct location. It seems that if Powershell doesn't find the profile location under Documents, or $HOME it defaults to the path C:\Powershell. However I am not sure - would be nice to have clear specification on this behaviour.

Comment: Syncing my Documents folder with OneDrive as well. To resolve this issue, I created a WindowsPowershell folder under my OneDrive Documents folder, and copied my Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1 into that folder. Powershell resolved the file and functioning on next load ;)

Comment: I hate this syncing crap.  Every time I try and tab-complete a cmdlet that would take 1 second normally now takes up to 3 minutes because it's loading the profile from a network share right off the bat, and I can't figure out why.  I removed the \\UNCSHAREPATH\PowerShell\ folder from PSModulePath, but it keeps repopulating.  I spent way too much time on this.  This and why a new laptop's `Enter-PSSession <computer/serverName>` gives me a Negotiate or Kerberos is disabled, transportLayerException.

Comment: Changed up what was enabled and disabled in gpedit, but no combination worked.  And I definitely didn't set it up last time, it just worked.  Yes, WinRM is running on all hosts as well as my laptop.